# Download aws-s3 attachment saved with paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, paperclip

I save image attachments with the paperclip gem in my rails 2.3 app to AWS S3. I would like to be able to allow the user to download the image attachment as an actual download instead of opening a new browser tab. When I saved the image attachment locally on the server I used:

```
picture_filename = RAILS_ROOT + '/public' + params[:picture_filename]
send_file(picture_filename, :type => 'text', :stream => "false", :disposition => 'attachment')
```

However, send_file does not work if the location is on aws-s3.

How is this achieved with the aws-sdk gem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have your s3 config setup up on your paperclip model correctly

such as

```
has_attached_file :picture,
:storage => :s3,
:url => ":s3_domain_url",
:s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
:path => "picture/:id/:filename"
```

Then in your controller action should be able to go something like

```
@pic = Picture.find(1)

send_file(@pic.picture.to_file, :type => @pic.picture_content_type, :disposition => "attachment", :filename => @pic.picture_file_name)
```

This should get the correct aws s3 path. Note the `.to_file` this was removed in later versions of paperclip but if you are using rails 2.3 you might have an earlier version.

Im currently using this to download using rails 3.2+ and paperclip 3.0+

```
send_file(Paperclip.io_adapters.for(@pic.picture).path, :type => @pic.picture_content_type, :disposition => "attachment", :filename => @pic.picture_file_name)
```

Comment: Your solution for Rails 2.3.18 and PaperClip 2.7.5 worked fine on my development machine with ruby 1.9.3. However, my host has ruby 1.8.7 and I get "can't convert Paperclip::Tempfile into String" error using send_file(@pic.picture.to_file, :type => @pic.picture_content_type, :disposition => "attachment", :filename => @pic.picture_file_name). Any ideas?

Comment: With ruby 1.8.7 you need to add .path to the .to_file: send_file(@pic.picture.to_file.path, :type => @pic.picture_content_type, :disposition => "attachment", :filename => @pic.picture_file_name)